# Which ios devices support​ offline speech recognition

Tags: iphone, ipad, speech

Which ios devices allow a user to do speech recognition (the microphone in the keyboard to type) when there is no internet connection (or a slow connection).

My brand new iPad mini cannot do it but some other devices can.

Is there a list or some other way to know?

Comment: Are you looking at Siri, Voice Control or dictation (speech to text) here? Which devices specifically are able to do offline speech recognition?

Comment: See   https://www.macobserver.com/tmo/article/quick-tip-offline-dictation-with-iphone-6s-and-iphone-6s-plus

Comment: Dictation, like when I am typing in an email I want to do it using speech recognition even if I am offline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be only those devices with the A9 processor.  If so, that would be iPhone 6s, 6s+, and iPad 7th Generation.

It seems logical that the A10 (iPhone 7, 7+) would also do it, but I don't know.

Comment: Dictation doesn't work on my 7+ if the phone is in Airplane mode, I also don't see the "You can use dictation even when you aren't connected to the Internet" note as described in https://www.macobserver.com/tmo/article/quick-tip-offline-dictation-with-iphone-6s-and-iphone-6s-plus.

Comment: Are you able to personally confirm that offline dictation works with the iPhone 6s (Plus) running the latest version of iOS (iOS 10.2.1)? From what I saw online, it was more of an "experimental" feature which was removed, which would explain why patrix doesn't have it on his 7 Plus.

Comment: @SkeletonBow  I don't have an a9 or a10 device, but there is this:  https://www.reddit.com/r/iphone/comments/55h9z8/apple_has_quietly_reenabled_offline_dictation_in/